# Issues restoring a Database in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

I took a project where I have to do a few fixes to a website and I'm having several problems trying to import the DB from a backup to my local computer.

The message I got is the following:

> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server
>   running version 12.00.2000. That version is incompatible with this
>   server, which is running version 11.00.3000. Either restore the
>   database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is
>   compatible with this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

The thing is I'm running SQL Server 2014 Management Studio and it is a 12.2000.8 version so it should work, but it doesn't.

As a second option I tried to generate the script (as I can connect to the remote DB) but it also doesn't let me. It just gives an error somewhere in the middle of the creation of the script.

Any ideas what could I be missing or what can I do to fix this?

I'm working with win 8.1, VS 2014 & SQL Server 2014 Management Studio everything up to date.

Comment: Sounds like SSMS (Management Studio) is the correct version, but the underlying SQL Server instance is an older version (2012).  Get the latest version of SQL Express and install a new instance for the easiest way to restore the backup: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx

Comment: What output do you get when you run `SELECT @@VERSION` ?? Most likely, you have SSMS 2014, but you're **connected** to a SQL Server **2012** instance (thus v11.00.3000). You **cannot** restore a 2014 database onto a 2012 instance - no matter what version of SSMS you're using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of the version of management studio you're using, the version of the database instance sounds like it's 2012. If you create a backup with 2014, you won't be able to restore on a 2012 instance.